# Why feedback is activating at more than 4V?

Tags: led, simulation, current-source, nmos

In this circuit:

[image]

I don't get why the current start flowing from more than 4V. I thought was due to threshold, but the same happens with an NPN as M2 or using an BS170. With this last one, everything start an 0.5V early than what you see below. Below is reported the behavior of the schematic above.

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: Just to be sure, is the value of Rs = 2Ω ?

Comment: Yes. Try to simulate.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out'

Answer (score 2):

Your curve is actually composed of 3 parts. 1 is from 0 to ~3.7 volts, with essentially zero amps. 2 is from about 3.7 to about 4.3 volts, and in this region current is essentially linear with respect to voltage. 3 is above 4.3 volts with a gradually limiting increase in current.

1) occurs with the NPN shut off due to 0 Vbe, and lasts until the supply voltage, through Rin, reaches the MOSFET gate threshold - in this case about 3.5 to 3.6 volts.

2) Further increase in supply voltage causes a rapid increase in diode current, which also produces a rapid increase in base voltage in the NPN, but not enough to turn it on.

3) When the supply voltage hits about 4.3 volts, diode current reaches nearly 200 mA. This produces about .5 volts on the NPN base , which is enough to start producing collector current  and reducing the rate of increase in the gate voltage. It starts at this low base voltage (less than the usually mentioned 0.6 to 0.7 volts) because Rin is so high that it takes very little base current to produce an effective collector current. As the supply voltage continues to increase, the transistor turns on more and more strongly, limiting the increase in gate voltage and therefor in base voltage.

To check this, add a circuit consisting of a MOSFET with gate voltage tied to your M2 gate, source to ground, and drain to DC supply by way of a 1k resistor. Monitor the drain voltage of the new MOSFET. You will see that the drain voltage drops to zero just before the diode current starts to increase.

And for what it's worth, the reason you don't see much change with Rin is that the NPN transistors you're using to simulate this have very low leakage current. If you try an older transistor such as a 2N2222, you'll see a much higher turn-on voltage. This is because leakage in the NPN acts as a voltage divider and reduces the M2 gate voltage. To check this, monitor the gate voltage of the MOSFET, and you will see that for your initial NPN the gate voltage closely follows the supply voltage until the NPN starts conducting. With an older, leakier NPN you'll see the gate voltage significantly reduced.

So the simple answer to your post question is: Because 4 volts is the sum of the MOSFET gate threshold and the NPN base conduction point.

Comment: Very clear. I've also verified what you said.

If I understood, with the 2N2222A, reducing the collector resistor will bring the knee of the curve of gate voltage at an higher value. I saw that from the simulations.
With the assumption that I see an higher leakage as a lower parallel ideal resistor between C-E: this means a lower voltage variation to the gate and so an higher current on drain to achieve the same drop on the "parallel resistor". And this bring an higher voltage on gate before the attenuation (negative feedback) became active.

Have I understood well?

Comment: I wouldn't use those exact terms, but I think you've got it.